# Did Yoda Intend On Training Leia As a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode V, *The Empire Strikes Back*, when Luke is leaving Dagobah, Obi-Wan, as a Force Ghost, says, "He is our last hope."  Yoda replies, "No, there is one other."

Was Yoda planning on training Leia as a Jedi, either in case Luke was killed or converted, or in addition to Luke?

Comment: In a couple of the books I read that were set post ROTJ, she refused Luke's attempts at training beyond some basic skills because she couldn't come to terms with the fact that Vader was her father as well.  Been a long time since I read them, but might have been the Thrawn series.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think that the answer lies right there in the question - "yes". Otherwise, she would NOT have been a hope. Remember, Yoda's "hope" was for Luke to **defeat** Vader, not to redeem him - the former requires one to be trained as a Jedi.

---

A really interesting angle on this comes if you consider the newly revealed Leigh Brackett's first draft of ESB script. Quoting an [article](http://www.craveonline.com/film/articles/138794-first-draft-of-the-empire-strikes-back-surfaces) on Craveonline:

> This script also provides a glimpse at a route the saga might have taken regarding Luke's twin sister. **This sister is mentioned—in Luke's presence-but she's someone other than Leia. She is identified as Nellith** (although this name is crossed out in the script, apparently because the writer realized that her name cannot be revealed to Luke--Vader can read Luke's mind) and was hidden by Skywalker, Sr. in a different part of the galaxy than Luke.
>
> Laurent Bouzereau reveals more about this lost sister in his book *Star Wars: The Annotated Screenplays*. Bouzereau mentions that Luke's twin was discussed in story meetings between Lucas and Brackett (which occurred from November 28 to December 2, 1977):  **“It was suggested that Luke's twin sister would be going through training at the same time that he was and become a Jedi Master as well. Eventually, in another episode, the story could deal with both Luke and his sister as Jedi Knights.”**  (Bouzereau, page 182)

---

**UPDATE:**

An additional (though later) canonical confirmation comes from ROTS novelization by Matthew Stover. As Yoda, Organa and Kenobi are deciding what to do at the end, Yoda says about training both twins in the future:

> "... Hidden, safe, the children must be kept. **Foundation of the new Jedi Order, *they* will be**."
> "We should split them up," Obi-Wan said. "Even if the Sith find one, the other may survive. I can take the boy, Master Yoda, and you take the girl. We can hide them away, keep them safe— train them as Anakin should have been trained—"
> "No." The ancient Master lowered his head again, closing his eyes, resting his chin on his hands that were folded over the head of his stick.
> Obi-Wan looked uncertain. "But how are they to learn the selfdiscipline a Jedi needs? How are they to master skills of the Force?"
> "Jedi training, the sole source of self-discipline is not. **When right is the time for skills to be taught, to us the living Force will bring *them***. Until then, wait we will, and watch, and learn."

Notice that he intends BOTH to be trained as Jedi.

Comment: That's an interesting tidbit: Yoda famously tried to condemn Luke as too old to begin training, but also actually refused the chance to start training him as an infant.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - the Force told him to do that

Comment: There are 2 paths in defeating Vader, kill him OR turn him back to Anakin (no longer Vader)...

Answer (score 20):

If Luke was killed or turned, then yes, I would think that Yoda would attempt to train Leia. However, Leia is a faint hope; Vader figured out pretty quickly that the Force was strong with Luke (or whoever was in that particular X-Wing). If Vader couldn't sense that Leia was a Force-sensitive during all that time he had her in captivity, she may well not be as powerful as Luke (they were fraternal twins, after all, and so not genetically identical). Obi-Wan and Yoda thus were betting heavily on Luke. That's why Obi-Wan, who knew that Leia was also Anakin's offspring, nevertheless thought that Luke was their only hope (even in RotJ, after having been countered by Yoda in ESB).

In the novelization of RotJ, it's explained in dialogue why Ben says what he says as far as Luke being the only hope; "The other he spoke of is your twin sister. She will find it no easier than you to defeat Vader". Leia has neither the training Luke has, nor would she have any more desire to kill Vader knowing he's her father. The Jedi's hopes were pinned early on Luke over Leia, primarily due to circumstance; Leia was in the custody of the Empire, and so Luke was the only one Ben could get to and try to convince. Had Luke met his fate before the events of ANH (he was a daredevil Skyhopper pilot in his spare time), Ben might have pre-emptively tried to get in touch with Leia through any remaining contacts on Alderraan, but that alternate universe never came to pass; he made contact with Luke, and was able to lead him far enough down the Jedi path to make a difference before he became one with the Force. Leia didn't receive any formal training in the Force until after the Battle of Endor, becoming something of a Jedi Consular in the New Republic.

Comment: "fraternal twins" - source? Sounds like an interesting fact

Comment: @DVK: doesn't fraternal simply mean [non identical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin#Fraternal.2FSororal_.28dizygotic.29_twins)?

Comment: By definition, twins of opposite genders must be fraternal. Dizygotal, if you must; two different eggs were released and fertilized. Identical twins, formed from a single zygote that splits completely in two in the process of its initial cell division, are always the same gender. The point was they obviously were genetically different, and so Leia isn't necessarily as Force-sensitive as Luke.

Comment: @KeithS - Gotcha. Incidentally, +1. And yes, from EU Leia wasn't as sensitive as Luke

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what they were thinking of, or original script ideas. All that matters is how the whole story turned out. So..every one lied to Luke and hid his father and sister from him for his own, as well as her, safety. And as far as Leia, and her role in saving the rebellion, think about her mother. Being a political figure is critical for gaining power or support. As well, her role in the rebellion greatly facilitated its success. And yes in later years she becomes a Jedi.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE. Your answer doesn't answer the question, does it ?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but when EMPIRE STRIKE BACK came out there was no twin sister to the story.

The whole "No, there is one other." was George Lucas leaving the door open for the second trilogy, to be sequels. This line was actually part of second script of EMPIRE. By the time Lucas started to work on RETURN OF THE JEDI (REVENGE OF THE JEDI back then), he decided that this was the end. The whole STAR WARS thing was too much for him. He lost his marriage and everything had taken sour turn for him.

But he needed to answer some questions... and just like in 1978, following the success of STAR WARS, when he decided that Father Skywalker and Darth Vader would be the very same person... (because they weren't up to that point) he had to find a quick answer to that "other one". Various ideas were thrown in, the one with Leia as the twin sister was chosen.

Comment: This is not quite accurate. If you look at the update to my answer (thanks for making me remember that detail), even the VERY first draft, in 1977, discussed Luke's twin sister who was also training to be a Jedi - though it wasn't Leia. So "no twin sister to the story" is not accurate. And Leia is strongly hinted to be connected to Luke at the end of the movie when he calles specifically to her throught the Force, and she hears him.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Sorry but there was no twin sister in any of the incarnation of the STAR WARS scripts.

The first draft was not in 1977. There was no sister but Luke was actually originally a girl.

Interviews with Lucas during the EMPIRE STRIKE BACK era has him clearly say that there this other is for a new character to be presented in the sequel trilogy.

He later changed his mind, when writing RETURN OF THE JEDI and decided not to do any sequel trilogy.

This is well documented.

Comment: Much like with the prequel trilogy, Lucas had to answer lots of things with RETURN OF THE JEDI. He then decided to have Leia as a twin sister.

In the final script of STAR WARS, it is clearly stated that Luke is 21 and Leia 18. Twins? Sadly no.

Unlike what Lucas wants us to believe, this wasn't all planned. And its fine with me. I just love STAR WARS too much and Lucas is free to do what ever he wants with it.

Comment: This could be an awesome answer if only you could provide links to references. Without them, it's just hearsay (By the way, I tend to agree with you: I think Georgie was making it all up as he went).

Comment: “This is well documented.” — Should be easy for you to provide a link to some of that documentation then.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought the " no there is one other " line was describing darth vaders gradual redemption back to being anakin skywalker

Comment: Yoda says, "[No, there is *another*](http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml)", and in either case, this doesn't address whether or not he intended to train Leia.

Answer (score -1):

Having read the final three books that have not yet been made into movies I have to conclude that Leia will be trained as a Jedi by Luke along with the twins she has with Han Solo although the twins are only born in the final book so there is not any information about the twins training.

Comment: Final three? So no more Star Wars books will be published? The twins have grown up in the books and a third Solo child has been born (and grown up). This answer is about 15 years outdated at best.