# To whom was Yoda referring when he said, "There is another?"

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, continuity, yoda

In the original trilogy Yoda refers to another hope:

> *Obi-Wan*: "That boy is our last hope."
>   *Yoda*: "No...there is another..."

The assumption being after seeing *Return of the Jedi* (Episode VI) that the other was Leia.

If, however, you consider the prequel trilogy canon, then this assumption depends greatly on your point of view*. Obi Wan knows about Leia (and for unknown reasons has discounted her as a hope), so Yoda must be referring to someone or something else.

Is there any canonical source as to what Yoda meant, or was uncle George setting us up for Episode VII?

*as a wise man once said

> you will find that many of the truths we cling to depend greatly on
>   our own point of view.

Just to add a bit of clarity: I was thinking about who Yoda was referring to when he was talking to Obi-Wan. When talking to Luke, it is obvious that Leia is the other (as he talks about a 'Skywalker'). It is not so obvious (after watching the prequel trilogy) that he means it when talking to Obi-Wan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did Yoda Intend On Training Leia As a Jedi?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/did-yoda-intend-on-training-leia-as-a-jedi)

Comment: @MarkRogers Related, but not duplicate.

Comment: Maybe Ben felt that an untrained Leia taking down the Emperor and restoring the Jedi order was not worth hoping for if the barely trained Luke should fail?

Comment: @jeremy-french, re: your edit - it's obvious that Leia is the other skywalker when Yoda is talking to Obi-Wan, but it's not obvious when Yoda is talking to Obi-Wan. Huh?

Comment: It was Leia - Obi-wan was just a sexist pig.

Comment: I always assumed it was a variance of (WARNING TVTROPES LINK!!!) http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AsYouKnow
Yoda knows of Leia, so does Obi-Wan, Luke has already flown off - so there is probably no one else on Dagobah - but US, the audience. Because, let's be honest, Ben is a manifestation through the Force, Yoda need not have actually spoken aloud.

Comment: “Obi Wan knows about Leia... so Yoda must be referring to someone or something else” — not necessarily. Obi-Wan might have decided that Leia doesn’t count as “a hope”, but Yoda might not agree with him. If we saw the rest of the conversation, it could have gone “OBI-WAN: You don’t mean Leia, surely. YODA: Indeed mean Leia I do. OBI-WAN: Come on Yode, she’s as useless as your weird sentence construction.”

Comment: (Note to the producers of *The Force Awakens*: yes, I am available for script work.)

Comment: Don't remember where, but I've heard of the possibility that Leia isn't actually Luke's sister.

Comment: additional related discussion: [Did Yoda definitely know who the other hope was?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91685/5184)

Comment: Are we absolutely sure there wasn't a third sibling to Luke and Leia, little mentioned in canon? Donald Skywalker, anyone?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense in ESB for Yoda to mean Leia, since he literally says seconds before this to Luke, to sacrifice her if he honors what she fights for.

Answer (score 101):

This dialogue from *Star Wars episode VI Return of the Jedi* made it clear it's Leia :

> **BEN:** *Then the Emperor has already won. You were our only hope.*
>
> **LUKE:** *Yoda spoke of another.*
>
> **BEN:** ***The other he spoke of is your twin sister.***
>
> **LUKE:** *But I have no sister.*
>
> **BEN:** *Hmm. To protect you both from the Emperor, you were hidden from your father when you were born. The Emperor knew, as I did, if Anakin were to have any offspring, they would
>   be a threat to him. That is the reason why your sister remains safely anonymous.*
>
> **LUKE:** *Leia! Leia's my sister.*

Comment: Good point. Then why does Ben not know of her, or assume that she has is not a hope?

Comment: Because he didn't had time to initiate her to the ways of the force. And with Yoda gone, who will?

Comment: Some people states that the truly hope isn't exactly Leia (who doesn't shows any force affinity during the original trilogy), but it's future children. Probably Yoda's power can trascende time and space and see the future of Leia's children, while Ben simply see that Leia hasn't the Force.

Comment: @Bardo She did shows force affinity during the original trilogy. Without any training, she used telepathy to communicate with Luke while he hung on the antenna behind Cloud City. While Luke initiated the communication, it's not something that she would be able to do if she didn't had the force with her.

Comment: That's not clear. Probably she's more attuned to it's brother than anyone more on the MF. Luke is about to die, recently shocked by it's father discovery and, although gaining in Force potential, far away to control all it's power. It's acceptable to think that's Luke's mind who stablish contact with his nearest affine mind in seek of help.

Comment: I'm going to split hairs here. But Yoda spoke to Luke of another sky-walk-er, which is Lea. As I said in the post, after watching the prequel trilogy it is not conceivable that Ben needs to be reminded of Lea. Hope != Skywalker

Comment: @Bardo That seem convoluted. After all, The last words of Yoda were *"Luke, the Force runs strong in your family.
Pass on what you have learned, Luke... There is...
another...Sky...Sky...walker."* He would not had used his last words to hint about a potential children from Leia, *"Always in motion is the future"*.

Comment: Also keep in mind, how does this work with Yoda's line to Luke in ESB where Luke asks "And sacrifice Han and Leia?" and he says "If you honor what they fight for...yes!" This is like literally seconds before he says to Obi-Wan "there is another".

Comment: Great answer, but it begs the question, how is it that ghost Ben does not know about Leia in ESB?

Comment: @JDoe He does know, see my comment up there. "he didn't had time to initiate her to the ways of the force. And with Yoda gone, who will?"

Answer (score 18):

As a further confirmation to DavRob, Episode 3 (at least Matthew Stover's novelization that was approved and edited by Lucas, not sure about the script of the movie) confirms that Yoda ALWAYS meant Leia by "another" hope:

> "... Hidden, safe, the **children** must be kept. **Foundation of the
>   new Jedi Order, **they** will be**."
>   "We should split them up," Obi-Wan said. "Even if the Sith find
>   one, **the other may survive**. I can take the boy, Master Yoda, and you
>   take the girl. We can hide **them** away, keep them safe— train **them**
>   as Anakin should have been trained —"
>   ... When right is the time for skills to be taught, to us the living Force will
>   bring **them**. Until then, wait we will, and watch, and learn."

Comment: That brings another question to mind:  If Yoda and Obi-Wan originally conspired to train them in the force, than why did Obi-Wan have to argue with Yoda about training Luke in Empire Strikes Back?

Comment: @SamIam - Old, Yoda was. Senile.

Comment: @DVK Debatable, that statement is. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6343/2841

Comment: @DVK: Old, Lucas was. Senile.

Comment: And what was one of features we know of how Anakin was supposed to be trained?  When he was very young, before he could develop emotional attachments to his family.  So what did Yoda and Ben proceed to do?  Leave them alone until they're adults and have had ample time to develop emotional attachments to friends and family, and leaving them only a matter of months to learn skill sets their opponents have spent decades mastering.  Those Jedi sure are smart.

Comment: @dmm When six Star Wars films you have made, look as good, you will not.

Comment: @SamIamsaysReinstateMonica - I always saw that scene not so much Obi-Wan trying to convince Yoda, but more like Yoda giving Luke a hard time and Obi-Wan showing up to say "Yoda, don't be an ass. Just train the boy already."

Answer (score 11):

If we are to assume that Yoda's statement that 'there is another hope' has any thematic relevance to the movie in which is takes place, Yoda must be referring to Vader, since Leia does not save the Galaxy. The entire Star Wars saga is about Anakin's redemption, and how his redemption is the only way in which the darkside can be defeated. Thematically, it makes no sense for Yoda to be referring to Leia, other than to state that the Jedi have no idea what they are talking about, which they certainly do not if they are referring to Leia.

Comment: Anakin was the greatest Jedi, and the only one capable of defeating the emperor.  Luke's refusal to give in to hatred and fear recalls Anakin to himself and leads to his redemption.  So Luke is the harbinger, and Anakin is the hope.

Comment: “since Leia does not save the Galaxy”. She never needs to, because Luke does it first. The first hope comes through.

Answer (score 2):

The original pre-SE/pre-Prequel novelization of *Return of the Jedi* explains very clearly that Leia was meant to be trained as another Jedi.

Ben and Luke are discussing whether or not Leia might be able to help sway Vader.

> "She hasn't been trained in the ways of the Jedi the way you have, Luke - but the Force is strong with her, as it is with all of your family. That is why your path crossed mine - because the Force in her must be nourished by a Jedi. You're the last Jedi now, Luke... but she returned to us - to me - to learn, and grow. Because it was her destiny to learn and grow; and mine to teach."

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the novel of ROTJ... Luke said "But you can't let the Emperor of Vader get their hands on her (Leia). Obi-wan said "She hasn't been trained in the ways of the force as you have Luke. You are strong and patient now, and you're ready for your final confrontation"

Luke was the only hope because if he failed, there was now NO one left to train Leia in the ways of the force. Yes, she would have the same potential, but it would be wasted because now that both Obi-Wan and Yoda were physically gone, there was no way that Leia could be trained as a Jedi.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to go against mainstream opinion . It is definitely **NOT Leia** . It could only be **redeemed Anakin Skywalker**. There are several reasons for this:

1. Like it or not, Leia is only supporting character in whole saga . Ok, she had Death Star plans in Episode 4, but after that her significance is much reduced. Yes, she is Force sensitive, but as far as we know, never near potential of her brother or father . And who would have trained her, even if she somehow escape from Endor ? Force ghosts ? From all that we know Jedi training requires grueling regime for months and years. Luke trained long and heard on Degobah, but despite all of that was no match for Palpatine . And as far we know, Force ghosts could appear only for short time (few minutes, or even seconds) . Otherwise, Yoda and Kenobi could train not one, but many Padawans across whole Galaxy, because there are still many Force sensitive children/younglings .
2. Significance of sentence ***There is another Skywalker*** is much increased in Clone Wars last episode "Sacrifice" . If you consider another Skywalker to be Leia, significance of this phrase would be practically non-existent. Both Luke and Obi-Wan Kenobi knew that Leia exists and that she has some Force talents . In the end, she doesn't do anything extraordinary, so why would  Force Priestess utter this phrase to bewildered Yoda as her (and years latter his) final words ? There must be something else .
3. Both Yoda and Kenobi **considered Anakin Skywalker to be as good as dead** . "More machine then a man", "Darth Vader betrayed and murdered your father" and especially ***Once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny, consume you it will.***
   Yoda thought and taught Luke that there is no coming back from Darth Side. This is old and dogmatic view of Jedi Order before Order 66. Force Priestess in last episodes of Clone Wars tried to teach him something else. Yoda understood that there is some Dark Side in everybody, even him. But yet he still thought he has nothing to learn from Sith (encounter with vision of Darth Bane and illusion of Sifo-Dyas) . In other words, he could not sense good in them - right until his dying moments. 
   Only then he realized that simple truth - Anakin Skywalker is still alive. Suppressed, wounded, half-mad but still father of the boy standing before him. And yes, redemption is possible - there is another Skywalker, one destined to destroy Sith and bring balance to the Force. Which he did .

Comment: Luke only trained for a few days (months at most) on Dagobah.

Comment: @Valorum Luke trained 1-6 months (various estimates)  in Empire Strikes Back , but he was not ready to face Vader then. In  RotJ his power is much grater, suggesting that he trained a lot between two episodes . Did he return to Degobah is unclear . Anyway, he did have "Jedi boot camp" behind him, something Leia could never achieve because she didn't have a tutor.

Comment: The Director's commentary is pretty clear that Luke (at this point) is potentially expendable **because another could be trained in his place**. That doesn't gel with it being Vader *at all*.

Answer (score -2):

There is a [speculation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5DLEDMKbyw) that "another" could be not a Skywalker at all, but **Ahsoka**. She was already trained in the ways of the Force and mastered lightsaber combat. Finally, she has already duelled Vader and survived it (end of *Rebels* Season 2).

That makes her a more powerful (than Leia) candidate to defeat Vader, as Leia is untrained, and there is no one left alive capable of training her.

upd: she IS alive by the end of RotJ, according to the *Rebels* finale.

However:

1. (out-of-universe) Ahsoka character was not even conceived at the time the Original Trilogy was created, making it a retcon
2. The Skywalker twins were purposefully hidden by Yoda and Obi-wan, as the last hope to restore the balance to The Force. In *Revenge of The Sith*, they speak of no one else.

Thus, it is only a fan theory.

Comment: "Nothing is certain if she is still alive at the time of RoTJ", she is seen in the finalie to Rebels which is set after the battle of Endor

Comment: @JeremyFrench, thanks! I have updated the answer

Answer (score -3):

When the line "that boy is our last hope" is said, Yoda gets bathed in a greenish blue light, representing Luke. However, when Yoda says, "no, there is another," he gets bathed in a red light, representing Darth Vader.
 You must remember that every element in a movie is an intentional choice, and that this isn't the only time that these colors are used to represent their affiliated characters, and let you know who is being discussed. The point here being that Darth Vader is the other. This makes sense since Darth Vader is actually the Hero of the story, in other words, it's about his journey and his path towards redemption. The story is merely being told through Luke's eyes.

This is why it is Darth Vader who finds his place among the Jedi Master by the end of the story. Furthermore, the thing people use to justify Leia as being the other hope is just Obi-Wan's quote, but as you'll recall, he didn't know who Yoda was referring to any more than the viewer did, and this is his own misconception, one which is used as a misdirect for the viewers. Luke is not present for all key elements of the story, which involve the struggle in the balance of the force, only Darth Vader is, because it's his story.

There is also Yoda’s last words, which echo his line in Empire, and which he says after Luke has learned that Vader is actually Anakin Skywalker:

YODA ... There is...another...Sky...Sky...walker.

The fact he says this after Vader acknowledges he is a Skywalker and not before, should also let you know he wasn't talking about Leia.

OBI-WAN: I will take the child and watch over him. Master Yoda, do you think Anakin's twins will be able to defeat Darth Sidious?

YODA: Strong the Force runs, in the Skywalker line. Hope, we can . . . Done, it is. Until the time is right, disappear we will.

This line doesn't mention Leia as an additional hope, it mentions BOTH TWINS as the original hope. Further proof that it is Darth Vader who is the other hope.

Furthermore, Obi-wan spoke with certainty all the time in the prequels, and was constantly wrong.

Look at the prophecy of the chosen one: "Another depiction of the prophecy was a cave painting in the Ophuchi Sanctuary. According to the Ophuchi interpretation, the painting showed an enslaved dove rising up and defeating a serpent that slowly tried to corrupt and destroy him to catch him as its prey. When the serpent was destroyed, rain that had not fallen in the desert for many years would fall again. The Ophuchi believed that a drought would overtake Tatooine the day that the Chosen One was born, and that he would be aided in his task by one called the Argus who would free the Chosen One from his shackles before vanquishing the serpent."

The enslaved dove, is Darth Vader. The serpent trying to corrupt him is Emperor Palpatine. The Argus is Luke, who causes Darth Vader to rebel against Emperor Palpatine. So you are telling me, YOU honestly think, the PERSON DESTINED TO RETURN THE BALANCE TO THE FORCE, who GEORGE LUCAS CONFIRMED WAS "officially the Chosen One and not Luke," wasn't the other hope, but Leia was?

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up what appears to be a fairly outlandish fan theory?