# Why did Yoda think that redemption from the Dark Side was not possible?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

Yoda didn't believe turning away from Dark Side is possible, and kept this belief right until his death. He famously said to Luke Skywalker:

> Once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny, consume you it will.

He may have changed this opinion moments before he died ("There is another Skywalker", i.e. Anakin Skywalker is still there somewhere in Vader). But this is beside the point. Assuming he didn't deliberately lie to Luke, at the time of Luke's training he didn't believe redemption is possible.

Yet he had example of abandoning Dark Side right before his eyes in the canon novel [Dark Disciple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Dark_Disciple):

> Asajj Ventress (Yoda did meet her as Sith assassin in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series, S01E01). She came to Jedi Council while Yoda was present and formally declared that she abandoned Dark Side. She also asked for help to save her lover Jedi Quinlan Vos who has also fallen to Dark Side. To cut long story short, in the end Ventress sacrificed her life to save Vos and turn him away from darkness. Both of them were redeemed.

So, my question is why did Yoda believe that redemption is not possible when he had witnessed these examples of Force users abandoning Dark Side ?

Comment: Making generalizations, Yoda was.

Comment: Talk bollocks, Yoda does.

Comment: In Yoda's voice, you read this.

Comment: spoilers, spoilers... I did not read the novel and it is now spoiled!

Comment: @C.Koca - Block the [tag:star-wars] tag, you must.

Comment: @Adamant Watched the movies and cartoons, I have. The books, I haven't read.

Comment: Why don't I remember the details of the question.. When did Ventress sacrifice her life?

Comment: @C.Koca Sorry for spoilers , didn't think I was.  :P

Comment: @Discovery Spoiled you will be, to kill me want you will :P

Comment: I always thought that Yoda is speaking of Leia when he mentions the "other Skywalker"

Comment: @DennisChristian - [He was](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91690/20774).

Comment: Why does a line uttered in a movie not line up with a book released 30 years later? That's never happened before.

Answer (score 9):

You are working from a false premise.  "[F]orever will it dominate your destiny," is not the same as, *There is no return from the Dark Side*.  The former is an accurate statement about Anakin's fate; even after his redemption, the fact that he had previously fallen to the Dark Side had a profound effect on the remainder of his brief life.  A convert to the Dark Side may be rescued, but the time spent under the spell of evil can never be expunged and will always be the most important fact of their existence.

Moreover, when Yoda and Ben are instructing Luke for the last time, Ben says that Luke needs to kill Vader.  This turns out to be wrong.  Yoda, though, only says that Luke must "confront" his father.  Again, Yoda's assessment is accurate, although not in the most obvious way.  ("Even the wise cannot see all ends."  "Difficult to see.  Always in motion is the future.")

Comment: So Yoda was telling the truth, from a certain point of view.

Comment: @Buzz Well... Anakin supposedly became Force Ghost jus like Yoda, and  Force Ghosts are not dominated by Dark Side, especially not forever. Or I missed something ? :P

Comment: You're assuming a Force Ghost can't feel pain/guilt over the actions he carried out while under the influence of the dark side. Do we know that's actually the case? Anakin might be beyond physical pain, but couldn't he still forever be troubled by his actions as Vader, full of regret or sorrow?

Comment: From Obi-Wan's *certain point of view*, couldn't you say that Luke *did* need to kill Vader? If his fall to the dark side was Darth Vader "killing" Anakin, wouldn't his redemption be "killing" Darth Vader?

Comment: @delinear Force Ghosts feeling pain and regret is somehow contrary to idea that they are selfless entities existing beyond space and time, understanding whole of the Force. Also, Force Ghosts feeling pain and regret is never mentioned in canon .