# Why didn't Yoda and Obi-Wan train Leia and Luke together?

Tags: star-wars

The Jedi were almost extinct, only Yoda and Obi-Wan remained... As their last shot, they trained Luke to become a Jedi and defeat Vader and the Emperor.

Later, Yoda states that if he failed, there was another hope. Leia, the twin sister, could be used too. But, since this was their last chance, and Luke was veery weaker than the Sith,

**Why didn't they train both Luke and Leia?**

It would be a lot easier to beat Vader if they attacked together. Obi-Wan could have just asked, in the force-vision at the Hoth system, for Luke to bring Leia with him to Dagobah...

Comment: i think the point here was to keep her a secret, as she had been the entire time. vadar has learned about luke, but he has no idea that leia is his daughter. and the question is kinda open ended, because they could have honestly went and actively searched out other force sensitive people if they wanted.

Comment: This is very closely related to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/did-yoda-intend-on-training-leia-as-a-jedi?rq=1). Possibly a duplicate, but I haven't cast a VTC.

Comment: Since Obi Wan was dead and Yoda nearly so, it does seem that they didn't plan the training of the twins as well as they could have.

Comment: @Null - I think DVK's answer to the other question answers this one too, at least as well as it can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

In part I believe that it was to keep Leia a secret from Vader and the Sith. Leila is also a girl, and maybe the creators didn't want the chosen one to be a girl. There are a lot of potential reasons, but the most logical would be that Luke was meant to be the main character just because the genre is geared towards boys, so they made the protagonist a male.

However, we know that all of Jedi Council knew that the chosen one was supposed to be a boy, which is why they thought it was Anikin. It would make sense of it was actually Luke all along, as to tie the entire series together.

Comment: You have some possible out-of-universe answers, but unless otherwise specified the question is looking for in-universe answers. Also, [Anakin is the Chosen One](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/was-luke-or-anakin-the-chosen-one).

Comment: Do you have a source on the council believing that the chosen one was necessarily a male? I don't recall the prophecy mentioning gender at all.

Comment: The chosen one was actually Anakin... not Luke